# How can select data from mysql using bash script and pass it to php?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql, php

This is what Im trying now

In PHP Im running the following sript:

```
exec('/home/user1/createinstanceinfolder.sh', $output, $return_var);

print_r($output);
```

Which is calling the following Bash script:

```
declare -A arr == $(sudo mysql -u root -h localhost -e "USE mydb;SELECT * FROM users")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
echo "$i"
done
```

Php is printing a empty array, what is wrong here?

Comment: Your script appears to have no shebang - are you sure php even interprets it with bash? What exactly do you expect `declare -A arr == $( ...)` to do? is the output of your mysql command suitable for assignment to an *associative* array? In any case, array assignments should look like `arr=( ... )`. Why are you putting stuff into an array, only to echo it back out? Did you test the script **outside** of php?

Comment: Why would you do this using BASH and not PYTHON? BY FAR easier

Comment: Here is how my bash script looks like now                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                           
 #!/bin/bash
declare -a arr = $(sudo mysql -u root -h localhost -e "USE mydb;SELECT * FROM users")

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
echo "$i"
done
Im new in ubuntu, Im not sure how to test it outside of PHP. What I want to do is to retrieve the info from mysql and return it to PHP

Comment: After retrieving this the bash scripts will also be responsible to create folders in var/www/mysite based on what fund in the database. I want to keep mysite with 755 and also dont want to give write permission to the web server thats why Im doing all this in BASH

Comment: This is what Im getting outside of php:                                                                                                  ./createinstanceinfolder.sh: line 7: declare: `=': not a valid identifier
./createinstanceinfolder.sh: line 7: declare: `5': not a valid identifier
./createinstanceinfolder.sh: line 7: declare: `111111111111': not a valid identifier
./createinstanceinfolder.sh: line 7: declare: `testuser@gmail.com': not a valid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fund the right syntax is:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -f        # disable globbing
IFS=$'\n'     # set field separator to NL (only)
arr=($(sudo mysql -u root -h localhost -e "USE mydb;SELECT * FROM users"))
 
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
done
```